# posting array in php from a table

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

have this html page where I input in some fields and post all values in a php. Here's my html code:

```
     <form action = 'preViewTallyHdr.php' method = 'POST' target="_blank">
        <p>Supplier Name & contact person:
          <input class = 'supplier' type = 'text' id = 'supplierInput' value = '' STYLE="color: blue"; size="47" name = "supplier">
        </p> 
        <p>Wood specie description: 
          <input class = 'woodSpe' type = 'text' id = 'woodSpecie' value = ''STYLE="color: blue"; size = "55" name = "wood">
        </p>
        <!--this is for viewing newly added planks (jqgrid)-->
        <table id="plankList"  name="plankList[]"></table>
        <div id="pgrid"></div>

        <!--this button will open another dialog (dialogAdd) for adding new plank-->        
        <input type ='button' id="btnAddnew" value = 'Add Plank'>   
        <input type = "Submit" value="Preview">  
     </form>

    <div id="dialogAdd" title="Plank Entry"> 
      <form method="post" action="#" id="plank_form">        
        <p>Plank number :
        <input type="text" class="integer" name="plank_number" id="plank_number"/></p>
        <p>Thickness:
        <input type="text" class="numeric" name="thickness" id="thickness"/></p>
        <p>Width:
        <input type="text" class="numeric" name="width" id="width"/></p>
        <p>Length:
        <input type="text" class="numeric" name="length_t" id="length_t"/></p>
        <p>Quantity:
        <input type="text" class="integer" name="quantity" id="quantity"/></p>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Evrytime I add a new plank, I create an array like this ti display in my jqgrid:

```
[{"plank_number":"1","thickness":"5","width":"7","length_t":"8","quantity":"1"},
 {"plank_number":"2","thickness":"5","width":"6","length_t":"7","quantity":"1"},
 {"plank_number":"3","thickness":"6","width":"7","length_t":"8","quantity":"1"}]
```

and will continue depending on how many plank a user input.

I already have a .php file that can output my supplier and wood specie, but i dont know how to display my post table data in there. Below is my code in php (no code for displaying table).

```
  <p>Supplier Name & contact person:<?php echo $_POST['supplier'];?><br/>
      </p> 
  <p>Wood specie description:<?php echo $_POST['wood'];?>
      </p>
  <?php 
        //this is for my table which i don't know how to start
  ?>
```

and also, can I also make a table from my data?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="plankList"  name="plankList[]"></table>
```

I'm not sure if above html mark up is right..

And if you have array or json format like this

```
[{"plank_number":"1","thickness":"5","width":"7","length_t":"8","quantity":"1"},
{"plank_number":"2","thickness":"5","width":"6","length_t":"7","quantity":"1"},
{"plank_number":"3","thickness":"6","width":"7","length_t":"8","quantity":"1"}]
```

You can post this in an ajax request (jquery).

Comment: i also tried that one but i dont know how to call my `planklist` array and put it in a grid.

Comment: have you checked the API docs of jqgrid ? [http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options]